# Selected item in dropdown does not get highlighted the next time I click on the dropdown

Tags: ms-access, mfc, visual-c++-2015

I have tried searching for a solution but could not come to one. The item selected from the combo box is not getting highlighted the second time I click on the drop down.

Example: suppose I have selected an item named dog from the combo box, now when I click the drop down, the control should be in on dog but that is not happening, instead again I have to scroll through the entire list in the drop down to get to the item dog.

```
 void Part::OnCbnSelchangeItemcombo()
 {
   CComboBox* pitem = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC ITEM_COMBO);
   int CurrentSelection = psize->GetCurSel();
   pitem->GetLBText(CurrentSelection,SelectedItem);
   SelectedItem.Trim();
 }
```

Comment: Please show [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) The code you have shown doesn't explain what is `pitem`, it has a typo `IDC ITEM_COMBO`, and it will not reproduce the problem even if it is fixed.

Comment: Why is this tagged `ms_access`?

Comment: There is a problem somewhere in the code you didn't show. There is not enough information in the question, so it's hard to anwser. The code you show here looks correct.

Comment: the cbnselchange message is fired when we select any option from the dropbox so i predict that the problem could be present in this function.

Comment: where can the problem exactly lie?

Comment: Without more code it's hard to tell. Make a dummy MFC application from scratch containing a combo box and see if you have the same problem there (however it should work). Cross check with your application to find what might be different.